# Why are polynomial activation functions not used

Tags: neural-networks, polynomial

Why are polynomial functions bad as activations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has been some work which experiments with quadratic activations -- see "neural tensor networks" but in general a disadvantage of second order and higher polynomials is that they don't have a bounded derivative, which could lead to exploding gradients.

Comment: This also applies more generally, in all kinds of maths&science domains: polynomials, especially higher ones, are _dangerous_ unless you have an a-priori rigidly confine range of input values. Neural networks are probably one of the applications where it's _least_ possible to give any such a-priori guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

**Nutshell**
So Polynomial activation functions don't work, since they fail to have the main property which makes neural networks interesting.

**Mathematical Reason**
Actually, there is a more rigorous reason why they are not used.  In
[this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608005801315), it is shown that the collection of all feed-forward neural networks can approximate any (reasonable) function *if and only if* the activation function is **not** a polynomial.

**Explicit Counter-Example**:
As an example, the simplest polynomial functions (which are non-constant) affine affine functions.  If affine functions could be used (ie the universal approximation peropty were to hold) then linear regressions could approximate any continuous function.  Which isn't the case.